# Accessing data from a custom serializer when being called by a nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer that calls other serializer, and this other serializer is a custom one that overrides the .to_representation() behaviour. How am I supposed to call this custom serializer from the first one, if I can't have access to the data sent from the view to the first serializer?

This is a quick example of the situation:

```
class OtherSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        # ... can't get data

class NestedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    someotherfield = OtherSerializer(somedata, many=True)  # this fails because obviously can't read "somedata", how to get access to it?
    boolfield = BooleanField()

NestedSerializer(data={'someotherfield': somedata, 'boolfield': False})  # this somedata is the one I'm talking above
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove the parameter somedata? Your code should look like:

```python
class NestedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    someotherfield = OtherSerializer(many=True)
    boolfield = BooleanField()
```

I would presume that the key 'someotherfield' is referring to a list, otherwise you wouldn't need many=True.

Let me know how is that working out for you.